# Remote Desktop or Streaming Software/Services that Supports Gaming

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, streaming, portable

I've simply been amazed by the quality and speed of [Onlive](http://Onlive.com), as this technology has the potential of making hardware requirements irrelevant to the average user. However, at the moment Onlive is only for remotely controlling video games, and not desktops or other devices in general.

---

I'm in pursuit of software or services that *can* accomplish this as well as Onlive does. 
**I need:**

- *viewer* (client) program portability (able to run on a USB stick)
- DirectX, OpenGL / full-screen game compatibility on the server side.
- Gaming-acceptable color/scaling quality and responsiveness.

I have a very powerful desktop at home and I want to be able to access this raw power from any other computer that I plug my USB stick into (in the same way Onlive gives gamers use of their powerful servers)

**What software/services can fulfil the above requirements?**

**NOTE:** please specify what features your suggestion doesn't have.

Comment: Oops, I mean *your

Comment: Checkout http://www.gaikai.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real revolutionary aspect of Onlive is the low latency they effect in their client system. If you are racing around a racetrack in Forza you definitely don't want to have to deal with a 250ms time gap between sending a brake command, and the brake command being rendered on your screen. Onlive is such a big deal because it was thought impossible by many on residential bandwidth up till the CES where it was unveiled, and still by many for a while afterwards.

Nearly all remote desktop solutions, prefer heavy security on the connection to a particular need for low latency. Windows remote desktop has noticeable latency issues for signals as simple as audio. The primary purpose of almost all remote desktop services is for presentations and technical support, and latency is of very low concern for those.

The world will be a better place if Onlive ever opens up their technology. In the meantime, I'm not optimistic about your options.

Comment: sigh... I doubt they'd give up such amazing stuff too...

Comment: But what are my other options rather than remote desktop then? How can I make a non-secure, optimized connection with my desktop and then stream the screen while sending back input?

Comment: If you know anybody who can help you, I'd strongly encourage you to get on github and start an opensource project on creating that technology from the tools that currently exist. Based on the needs you've given, the open technology doesn't exist to meet your function.

Comment: What might those tools be? Please answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551698/tools-libs-software-that-can-be-used-to-create-gaming-enabled-remote-desktop-s

Answer (score 2):

The following are possible candidates :

[TrueRemote](http://download.cnet.com/TrueRemote/3000-7240_4-75169977.html)
[NeoRouter](http://www.pendriveapps.com/neorouter-free-portable-remote-desktop/)
[2X-Client Portable](http://www.pendriveapps.com/2x-client-portable-remote-desktop/)
[ZeroRemote](http://www.pendriveapps.com/portable-remote-desktop-zeroremote/) (older version of TrueRemote)

I cannot vouch for any of them, as I am not a user of remote games.

Comment: Which of the products on the 2X site should be used for server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Try [VirtualGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualGL). It is a software shim that redirects OpenGL calls performed on a networked system (e.g., a thin-client) to hardware accelerator(s) on another system (e.g., a server) and then displays the results on the client.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.