# bandwith issue with remote gaming in local network

Tags: streaming, remote, gaming, steam

The question is similar but not identical to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/394171/remote-desktop-or-streaming-software-services-that-supports-gaming) one.

I've got a powerful gaming PC, which is a little noisy.
While playing competetive FPS and such, this isn't much of a problem due my headphones block the noise.

However, playing couch-coop with friends is no fun with it, due it's too loud.
Also, sometimes I like to play a SP RPG or something, where high fps doesn't matter and a reasonable ping is no problem.

The setting is as following:
 - Strong gaming pc with i7 CPU and Crossfire 280x as computing machine
 - HTPC with quadcore Intel Celeron as displaying machine
 - Some LG TV as displaying device
 - Connected via wlan (300mbs)

I looked at Steams in house streaming, but it doesn't work with my TV (It says display device is reacting too slow).

After reading a little, It seems like the biggest issue is the limited bandwith of 300mbs. I've no problem playing at 720p, but for steams stream, it still wont work.

What possibilities do I have to lower the requiered bandwith, except even lower resolutions?
Maybe a way to lock fps to 20fps, lowering specific settings (like SOAA) or something?

Alternatively;
Is there any devide where I can plug in a HDMI-TV for output and two xbox360 controller for input, which can perform as some kind of terminal?

The games I would like to stream don't require the crossfire power at all.
I've got two GPUs. Isn't there some kind of server-software which I can use to assign one GPU for rendering one GPU for encoding the rendered material?
This would lower the required bandwith in a way, that the celeron could receive the encodet material, decode it and bring it up to the TV.

Comment: I can't believe that you consider playing with 20 fps... I also doubt that 300 mbps wouldn't be enough... But you could confirm that by connecting your TV using a lan cable (1 Gbit) to your network. Tbh I couldn't think of a reliable streaming configuration directly to your TV. But I think I've heard of a solution that you can pair Win10 with a XBOX and play over the XBOX Win10 games. Do you have a xbox? =) Anyway I think the best thought would be to get your PC silent... Bigger aircondition or even watercooling would be my choice tbh...

Comment: What could also work is a wireless hdmi solution. But I have no real experience with such things...

Comment: Watercooling is no an option due the price. I am okay with 20fps for some little partygames

Comment: You've got a crossfire 280x system + i7 CPU, but can't afford watercooling? Hm :) Anyway... According to http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/?l=english you have to login to Steam on another device. Does your TV support steam? If not do you have a laptop you could plug into your TV?

Comment: I've got a Celeron based HTPC plugged into the TV, so logging into steam on both sides is not the problem.
Watercooling is very expensive dude :D
My GPUs aren't at reference design, there's only one fitting coolerblock which is very expensive (almost the price of the card itself, for both). The pc is very quiet without the GPUs, but these are pretty noisy.

Comment: Ok - then sorry :) I thought of a reference design water cooling, that isn't too expensive. I've missed/forgot the HTPC part - sorry about that. Can you try to connect your HTPC to your wired network to check if it's really about your wifi connection? Honestly I can't believe that -.- (unless you have a really bad signal strength)

Comment: ´ I will check a direct LAN connection later at home. The exact configuration is >>> i7-PC -> cat6 cable -> router -> wlan -> Celeron-PC -> TV <<<
 I'll also check if skiping the router and connecting both pcs via wlan directly performs as required.

Comment: I know this is a little old now, but have you considered powerline adaptors to increase your maximum connection speed? Something like these: 

http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/computing-accessories/networking/powerline/netgear-pl1200-powerline-adapter-kit-twin-pack-10130788-pdt.html?gclid=CjwKEAiA_ra1BRDV-byb_aDqpQoSJAA-ofB93UX4oLcnllzhvxlQMXBNedWsZ28XD7nBYyELCcUizxoCehnw_wcB&srcid=198&cmpid=ppc~gg~~~Exact&mctag=gg_goog_7904&s_kwcid=AL!3391!3!75233967139!!!g!115931573540!&ef_id=VhLw6AAABAR9YSOU:20160201000936:s

As even though they will not reach 1200 mbps they will almost certainly get above 300.